# Footer not inheriting class from css but accepting another?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a basic footer setup in Bootstrap framework with custom test. The HTML:

```
<footer class="footer navbar-custom-footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column">
                Some Rights Reserved.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

And the CSS:

```
.navbar-custom-footer {
    background-color:#7BAFD4;
    color:#B7C0E0;
    border-radius:0;
    font-size: 1em;
}     

.navbar-custom-footer .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color:#121E4B;
 }

.navbar-custom-footer .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #121E4B;
    background-color:transparent;
}

.navbar-custom-footer .navbar-brand {
    color:#eeeeee;
}
```

This is the exact copy of my header with custom tags and it will ONLY apply the css when using the original which is the following:

```
.navbar-custom {
     background-color:#7BAFD4;
     color:#B7C0E0;
     border-radius:0;
     font-size: 1em;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
      color:#121E4B;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #121E4B;
    background-color:transparent;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
    color:#eeeeee;
}
```

As you can see it should be inheriting the same? When looking at it through firebug it doesn't show the class working but does on the latter. It's definitely starting to drive me nuts as a new developer who is learning while going!

Comment: you can try it out with !important to the attribute what you want it on the screen

Comment: I don't understand what is not working. You are using only *.navbar-custom-footer* so all the other stuff (navbar-nav, active, etc etc) is not used in the html you provided

Comment: I tried this as well and it did not work Parthasarathy. @GiuServ, I don't understand either... And the other attributes don't matter for the footer at this point but will, but I can't even get the background to display so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: @Jesse730 can you explain what is your expected result? What's the problem with?  The footer get the style of the navbar-custom-footer class

Comment: @GiuServ, Overall I'm trying to style my footer but nothing is working except for previous attributes, such as .navbar-custom. If that makes sense. The footer is not getting the style from .navbar-custom-footer on my end.

Comment: There is an element  `footer`, but what is class `footer`? Is class `footer` defined anywhere?

Comment: Maybe, you should define your custom styles _after_ bootsrap.css has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, so if it doesn't works, probably you're not including the stylesheet containing your rules.

```html
<style>
  .navbar-custom-footer {
    background-color: #7BAFD4;
    color: #B7C0E0;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
  }
</style>

<footer class="footer navbar-custom-footer navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        Some Rights Reserved.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```